# Have you previously applied to enter or remain in canada? What should I put?

Tags: canada, applications, application-status

I was applied for a permanent residence visa for canada, they declined on 2005. In 2012 I entered in canada with swazi passport (while allow port entry). Now I am applying for a visit visa with swazi passport.

So what should I put yes or no?

If yes what should I write. Ex. In 2012 i enterd in canada but I didnt apply for remain in canada.

Comment: It cannot possibly be a good idea to lie on your visa application when they can so easily determine the facts!

Comment: It's interesting how almost all "should I lie or tell the truth?" questions come from certain specific areas.

Comment: What exactly is unclear about a question requiring a Yes or No answer?

Answer (score 10):

You should be truthful.  That means you should answer yes, because you applied in 2005.